# Details about inheriting IDisposable?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've been tasked with going through some old code at work to clean it up and I stumbled across a class:

```
public class XMLLayer : Object, IDisposable
```

First I find that the explicit Object inheritance is unnecessary, but then I find that the dispose method is rather useless:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose();
}
```

Nowhere is an instance of XMLLayer in a `using` block, having its `Dispose()` explicitly called, or being placed in a `IDisposable` variable (polymorphism).

Am I wrong in assuming that the idea of the Dispose method was to add your own custom cleanup code for the class?

Comment: Are you saying that the `Dispose` method calls itself?

Comment: Woa, calling Dispose there is probably going to result in a stack overflow...

Comment: I think the original developer thought `Dispose` meant "dispose of the process". You know, as in, send it to binary hell.

Comment: Your assumption is correct about running custom cleanup code for an object in Dispose. You don't need to call Dispose() on an object if it is instantiated with using statement. It is done for you automatically when the object goes out of the using statement scope.

Comment: @Gabe, @Etienne de Martel, actually, it would. This is the original code (cut and paste) so that would be a problem. My best guess is that he meant base.Dispose() (which does not exist). There might be a reason he doesn't work here any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Am I wrong in assuming that the idea
>   of the Dispose method was to add your
>   own custom cleanup code for the class?

See the following question and its accepted answer:

> [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

Answer (score 1):

That method isn't just useless - it'll cause a `StackOverflowException` and terminate the app if it's ever called (or just hang that thread forever, if the JIT has made used tail recursion).

Is there anything in `XMLLayer` which looks like it really *needs* to be disposed? When C# was new, some people decided to always implement `IDisposable` "just in case". Fortunately that doesn't happen much these days, as far as I can see.

You should implement `IDisposable` if it are directly or indirectly holds an unmanaged resource - e.g. if there's a field of type `Stream`.

Comment: Not to me. There's a dozen strings, another class (LayerInfo) with the same IDisposable issue (including EXACT same endlessly recursive Dispose function), and a List<LayerInfo>.

Comment: @Corey: Sounds like now is the time to remove the Dispose method and the whole of `: Object, IDisposable` :)

Answer (score 1):

That dispose doesn't seem so much useless as it is dangerous. it will call itself until eventually it kills the application with a `StackOverflowException`

You are correct that `Dispose` is for cleanup. But it's mainly for cleanup of unmanaged resources. Those are the resources that that .NET can't even know exists and therefore won't cleanup either

Answer (score 0):

No you're right. If that `Dispose()` method were ever called, it would just call itself repeatedly forever anyway, which is a pretty good indication it's never being used.